# How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size

How does one change the font size for all elements (ticks, labels, title) on a matplotlib plot?

I know how to change the tick label sizes, this is done with:

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=20) 
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
```

But how does one change the rest?

Answer (score 1131, accepted):

From the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc),

```
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22}

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
```

This sets the font of all items to the font specified by the kwargs object, `font`.

Alternatively, you could also use the `rcParams` `update` method as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441839/605121):

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
```

or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
```

You can find a full list of available properties on the [Customizing matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

Comment: nice, except it override any fontsize property found on it's way è_é

Comment: Where can I find more options for elements like `'family'`, `'weight'`, etc.?

Comment: @haccks I added a link to the customizing matplotlib page in the answer.

Comment: @HermanSchaaf; I visited that page before. I would like to know all the options for `'family'` Like `'normal'`, `'sans-serif'`, etc.

Comment: Since many people start with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, you might like to point out that `pyplot` has `rc` as well. You can do `plt.rc(...` without having to change your imports.

Comment: Does this permanently mess up the maplotlib defaults for fontsize??

Comment: For the impatient: The default font size is 10, as in the second link.

Comment: @LondonRob `plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':22})` works, too. Thanks.

Comment: @haccks for all options run plt.rcParams.keys()

Comment: I believe 'weight' is no longer valid and is now 'font.weight'

Comment: @user32882 - not permanently, it's not saved to disk, but I would assume it would change subsequent plots generated in the same code unless the original value is stored and restored, which is no always convenient.  You can do something like `for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()): label.set_fontsize(22)` to affect text size in a single figure.

Comment: If you want to temporarily change the font size, `plt.style.context` will accept a dictionary of `rcParams` like so: 

`with plt.style.context({'font.size': 22}):`

Comment: In Colab notebook will increase the font size on the screen, but *not* on a print. To fix this you must *also* add `dpi` e.g. `plt.figure(dpi=80)`

Comment: I would suggest `'family' : 'Sans'` that will resolve to something sensible

Comment: It's funny: The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc) uses `'size'   : 'larger'` in one of the examples, but when I try out that example, I get `ValueError: Key font.size: Could not convert 'larger' to float`. Your code on the other hand, `'size'   : 22`, worked.

Comment: Looking at the documentation is always a good idea

Answer (score 622):

If you are a control freak like me, you may want to explicitly set all your font sizes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
BIGGER_SIZE = 12

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title
```

Note that you can also set the sizes calling the `rc` method on `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib

SMALL_SIZE = 8
matplotlib.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)
matplotlib.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)

# and so on ...
```

Comment: I tried many of the answers. This one looks the best, at least in Jupyter notebooks. Just copy the above block at the top and customize the three font size constants.

Comment: For me the title size didn't work. I used: ``plt.rc('axes', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)``

Comment: I think you can combine all settings for the same object into one line. E.g., `plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE, labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)`

Comment: I tried aome answers. This one is the best!

Answer (score 270):

If you want to change the fontsize for just a specific plot that has already been created, try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='title')
for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(20)
```

Comment: My purpose was to have the font of x-y labels, ticks and the titles to be of different sizes. A modified version of this worked so well for me.

Comment: To get the legends as well use ax.legend().get_texts(). Tested on Matplotlib 1.4.

Comment: Might need an `ax=plt.gca()` if the plot was created without defining an axis.

Comment: @JamesS. Rather use `ax.get_legend().get_texts()`, because `ax.legend()` redraws the whole legend with default parameters on top of returning the value of `ax.get_legend()`.

Comment: `ax.get_legend().get_texts()` returns a list of each item in your legend.  So, to change the font size for one of the entries you need to do something like:

`ax.get_legend().get_texts()[0].set_fontsize(20)`

Answer (score 231):

```
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
```

Comment: In may case this solution works only if I create a first plot, then "update" as suggested, which leads to updated font size for new figures. Maybe the first plot is necessary to initialize rcParams...

Answer (score 86):

This answer is for anyone trying to change all the fonts, including for the legend, and for anyone trying to use different fonts and sizes for each thing. It does not use rc (which doesn't seem to work for me). It is perhaps a bit cumbersome but I could not get to grips with any other method, personally.

I have worked out a slightly different, less cluttered approach than my original answer below. It allows any font on your system, even `.otf` fonts. To have separate fonts for each thing, just write more `font_path` and `font_prop` like variables.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import matplotlib.ticker
# Workaround for Matplotlib 2.0.0 log axes bug https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8017 :
# matplotlib.ticker._mathdefault = lambda x: '\\mathdefault{%s}'%x 

# Set the font properties (can use more variables for more fonts)
font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\AGaramondPro-Regular.otf'
font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=font_path, size=14)

ax = plt.subplot() # Defines ax variable by creating an empty plot

# Define the data to be plotted
x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = x + np.random.normal(x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b+', label='Data points')

for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_fontproperties(font_prop)
    label.set_fontsize(13) # Size here overrides font_prop

plt.title("Exponentially decaying oscillations", fontproperties=font_prop,
          size=16, verticalalignment='bottom') # Size here overrides font_prop
plt.xlabel("Time", fontproperties=font_prop)
plt.ylabel("Amplitude", fontproperties=font_prop)
plt.text(0, 0, "Misc text", fontproperties=font_prop)

lgd = plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop=font_prop) # NB different 'prop' argument for legend
lgd.set_title("Legend", prop=font_prop)

plt.show()
```

---

**Original answer**

This basically combines ryggyr's answer here with other answers on SO.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

# Set the font dictionaries (for plot title and axis titles)
title_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'16', 'color':'black', 'weight':'normal',
              'verticalalignment':'bottom'} # Bottom vertical alignment for more space
axis_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'14'}

# Set the font properties (for use in legend)   
font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf'
font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=font_path, size=14)

ax = plt.subplot() # Defines ax variable by creating an empty plot

# Set the tick labels font
for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_fontname('Arial')
    label.set_fontsize(13)

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = x + np.random.normal(x) # Just simulates some data

plt.plot(x, y, 'b+', label='Data points')
plt.xlabel("x axis", **axis_font)
plt.ylabel("y axis", **axis_font)
plt.title("Misc graph", **title_font)
plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop=font_prop, numpoints=1)
plt.text(0, 0, "Misc text", **title_font)
plt.show()
```

By having several font dictionaries, you can choose different fonts/sizes/weights/colours for the various titles, choose the font for the tick labels, and choose the font for the legend, all independently.

Answer (score 71):

Here is a totally *different* approach that works surprisingly well to change the font sizes:

Change the **figure size**!

I usually use code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(0,6.28,21)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), '-^', label="1 Hz")
ax.set_title("Oscillator Output")
ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
ax.set_ylabel("Output (V)")
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend(loc=1)
fig.savefig('Basic.png', dpi=300)
```

The *smaller* you make the figure size, the *larger* the font is *relative to the plot*. This also upscales the markers. Note I also set the `dpi` or dot per inch. I learned this from a posting the AMTA (American Modeling Teacher of America) forum.
Example from above code: [image]

Comment: To avoid the axis label being cut-off, save figure with the `bbox_inches` argument

    `fig.savefig('Basic.png', bbox_inches="tight")`

Comment: What if I am NOT saving the figure? I am plotting in Juypter Notebook and the resulting axis labels get cut-off.

Comment: Thanks!  Pointing out the dpi settings was extremely helpful to me in preparing printable versions of my plots without having to adjust all the line sizes, font sizes, etc.

Comment: To prevent the label cut-off, also in the notebook as @Zythyr asks, you can use `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: @Zythyr You can use the dpi=XXX argument also in the call of plt.figure(): `plt.figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=300)` to achieve the same result without saving

Comment: I am grateful that you posted this answer here! It addressed the root problem that my 'font size' increase was attempting to solve.

Answer (score 50):

You can use `plt.rcParams["font.size"]` for setting `font_size` in `matplotlib` and also you can use `plt.rcParams["font.family"]` for setting `font_family` in `matplotlib`. Try this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

label = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x = [0.001906,0.000571308,0.0020305,0.0037422,0.0047095,0.000846667,0.000819,0.000907]
y = [0.2943301,0.047778308,0.048003167,0.1770876,0.532489833,0.024611333,0.157498667,0.0272095]


plt.ylabel('eigen centrality')
plt.xlabel('betweenness centrality')
plt.text(0.001906, 0.2943301, '1 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.000571308, 0.047778308, '2 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.0020305, 0.048003167, '3 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.0037422, 0.1770876, '4 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.0047095, 0.532489833, '5 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.000846667, 0.024611333, '6 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.000819, 0.157498667, '7 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.text(0.000907, 0.0272095, '8 ', ha='right', va='center')
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = "50"
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='blue')
```

[image: Please, see the output:]

Answer (score 49):

Use `plt.tick_params(labelsize=14)`

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Doesn't this just change the tick font size?

Comment: Ant thing similar for legend?

Answer (score 37):

Here is what I generally use in Jupyter Notebook:

```
# Jupyter Notebook settings

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:95% !important; }</style>"))
%autosave 0
%matplotlib inline
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"


# Imports for data analysis
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 2500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 2000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

#size=25
size=15
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'large',
          'figure.figsize': (20,8),
          'axes.labelsize': size,
          'axes.titlesize': size,
          'xtick.labelsize': size*0.75,
          'ytick.labelsize': size*0.75,
          'axes.titlepad': 25}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

Answer (score 15):

The changes to the `rcParams` are very granular, most of the time all you want is just scaling all of the font sizes so they can be seen better in your figure. The figure size is a good trick but then you have to carry it for all of your figures. Another way (not purely matplotlib, or maybe overkill if you don't use seaborn) is to just set the font scale with seaborn:

```
sns.set_context('paper', font_scale=1.4)
```

DISCLAIMER: I know, if you only use matplotlib then probably you don't want to install a whole module for just scaling your plots (I mean why not) or if you use seaborn, then you have more control over the options. But there's the case where you have the seaborn in your data science virtual env but not using it in this notebook. Anyway, yet another solution.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the above stuff:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

fontPath = "/usr/share/fonts/abc.ttf"
font = fm.FontProperties(fname=fontPath, size=10)
font2 = fm.FontProperties(fname=fontPath, size=24)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(32, 24))
fig.text(0.5, 0.93, "This is my Title", horizontalalignment='center', fontproperties=font2)

plot = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

plot.xaxis.get_label().set_fontproperties(font)
plot.yaxis.get_label().set_fontproperties(font)
plot.legend(loc='upper right', prop=font)

for label in (plot.get_xticklabels() + plot.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_fontproperties(font)
```

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to point out that both the [Herman Schaaf's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900167/2229448) and [Pedro M Duarte's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566040/2229448) answers work but you have to do that before instantiating `subplots()`, these settings will not affect already instantiated objects. I know it's not a brainer but I spent quite some time figuring out why are those answers not working for me when I was trying to use these changes after calling subplots().

For eg:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6,})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#create your plot
plt.show()
```

or

```
SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
BIGGER_SIZE = 12

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#create your plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

I totally agree with Prof Huster that the simplest way to proceed is to change the size of the figure, which allows keeping the default fonts. I just had to complement this with a bbox_inches option when saving the figure as a pdf because the axis labels were cut.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.savefig('Basic.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an extension to Marius Retegan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441839/8288497). You can make a separate JSON file with all your modifications and than load it with rcParams.update. The changes will only apply to the current script. So

```
import json
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, rcParams

s = json.load(open("example_file.json")
rcParams.update(s)
```

and save this 'example_file.json' in the same folder.

```
{
  "lines.linewidth": 2.0,
  "axes.edgecolor": "#bcbcbc",
  "patch.linewidth": 0.5,
  "legend.fancybox": true,
  "axes.color_cycle": [
    "#348ABD",
    "#A60628",
    "#7A68A6",
    "#467821",
    "#CF4457",
    "#188487",
    "#E24A33"
  ],
  "axes.facecolor": "#eeeeee",
  "axes.labelsize": "large",
  "axes.grid": true,
  "patch.edgecolor": "#eeeeee",
  "axes.titlesize": "x-large",
  "svg.fonttype": "path",
  "examples.directory": ""
}
```

Comment: Or using matplotlib's styling, which is very similar to your idea: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Answer (score 3):

It is mentioned in a comment but deserves its own answer:

Modify **both** `figsize=` and `dpi=` in conjunction to adjust the figure size and the scale of all text labels:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)
```

(or shorter:)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)
```

It's a bit tricky:

1. `figsize` actually controls the scale of the text *relative* to the plot extent (as well as the aspect ratio of the plot).
2. `dpi` adjusts the size of the figure within the notebook (keeping constant the relative scale of the text and the plot aspect ratio).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a modified version of the answer by @ryggyr that allows for more control over the individual parameters and works on multiple subplots:

```
def set_fontsizes(axes,size,title=np.nan,xlabel=np.nan,ylabel=np.nan,xticks=np.nan,yticks=np.nan):
    if type(axes) != 'numpy.ndarray':
        axes=np.array([axes])
    
    options = [title,xlabel,ylabel,xticks,yticks]
    for i in range(len(options)):
        if np.isnan(options[i]):
            options[i]=size
        
    title,xlabel,ylabel,xticks,yticks=options
    
    for ax in axes.flatten():
        ax.title.set_fontsize(title)
        ax.xaxis.label.set_size(xlabel)
        ax.yaxis.label.set_size(ylabel)
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=xticks)
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=yticks)
```