# arabic reshaper.reshape() does not work properly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, arabic, bidi

I'm working with arabic_reshaper to display my data from the CSV file (i saved the file using the save as type: CSV UTF-8(Comma delimited))

```
To                   From
أَبُو كَامِلٍ الْجَحْدَرِيُّ          عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ
عَبْدُ الْوَاحِدِ               الْأَعْمَشُ
```

I would like display the graph using networkx as follow:

[arabic graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij06y.png)

My codes are as follow

```
import arabic_reshaper

data = pd.read_csv('textArab6.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2,arabic_reshaper.reshape('From'),arabic_reshaper.reshape('To'))
nx.draw(G,
        with_labels=True,
        node_color="skyblue",
        node_size=5000,
       )
```

Definitey before i post my question here, i already referred from this url:
[Right-to-left Support in Python Networkx and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772950/right-to-left-support-in-python-networkx-and-matplotlib)
However the codes sample showed that the letter was not extracted from a csv file.
My problem is that, how to display the arabic letters properly in graph in which the data taken from a csv file.

Comment: Have you tried directly doing `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'From','To')`? Seems to display without problems for me

Comment: @yatu,  yeah i did. It stil did not work. Each arabic characters did not connected each other

Comment: So each arabic string is not a node? Please can you make that clearer?

Comment: The graph shows that each Arabic string is a node, They're written from left to right and not attached.

Comment: Yes, tha's true. I attached the image in the above link >> arabic graph