# How can I change the font size using seaborn FacetGrid?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have plotted my data with `factorplot` in `seaborn` and get `facetgrid` object, but still cannot understand how the following attributes could be set in such a plot:

1. Legend size: when I plot lots of variables, I get very small legends, with small fonts.
2. Font sizes of y and x labels (a similar problem as above)

Comment: The responses below are correct and should help you out, but I would say it sounds like you're plotting in the IPython notebook and so the issue isn't really anything to do with seaborn but that the notebook scales down figures if they end up larger than the div allotted to them. If you save the figure, everything should be the size that you expect.

Comment: Also if you are plotting a lot of variables on the columns and don't have a row variable, you could use `col_wrap` to "wrap" the facets onto multiple rows, which might help.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can scale up the fonts in your call to `sns.set()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
x = np.random.normal(size=37)
y = np.random.lognormal(size=37)

# defaults
sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, marker='s', linestyle='none', label='small')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.1))
```

[image]

```
sns.set(font_scale=5)  # crazy big
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, marker='s', linestyle='none', label='big')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.3))
```

[image]

Comment: Size is relative to the default matplotlib font size. For me it was better to change the font size right there with plt.rc() calls at the top of my script or Jupyter notebook. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot

Comment: This seems to override the chosen theme.

Comment: This is bad because it changes the figure layout completely, not just the font.

Comment: @SomJura if you have a fixed image size, your choices are to: a) adjust the layout so they fit or b) let them be cutoff by the figure boundaries. So not just "bad" but also, "necessary" and "practical"

Comment: @PaulH I agree with this. The issue is rather that some more parameters are changed silently, under the hood, when `sns.set()` is invoked. For example the background colour of the plotting area is changed to seaborn default. @CookieMaster mentions something similar.

Answer (score 52):

The `FacetGrid` plot does produce pretty small labels. While @paul-h has described the use of `sns.set` as a way to the change the font scaling, it may not be the optimal solution since it will change the `font_scale` setting for all plots.

You could use the [`seaborn.plotting_context`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.plotting_context.html) to change the settings for just the current plot:

```
with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=1.5):
    sns.factorplot(x, y ...)
```

Comment: @mwaskom says " `font_scale` is ignored if context is `None`, so you want `plotting_context("notebook", font_scale=5.5)` or similar."  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31865996/1135316)

Answer (score 18):

I've made some modifications to @paul-H code, such that you can independently set the font size for the x/y axes and legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
x = np.random.normal(size=37)
y = np.random.lognormal(size=37)

# defaults                                                                                                         
sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, marker='s', linestyle='none', label='small')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=20,bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.1))
ax.set_xlabel('X_axi',fontsize=20);
ax.set_ylabel('Y_axis',fontsize=20);

plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: very good and creative idea

Answer (score 10):

For the legend, you can use this

```
plt.setp(g._legend.get_title(), fontsize=20)
```

Where g is your facetgrid object returned after you call the function making it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
g = sns.catplot(x="X Axis", hue="Class", kind="count", legend=False, data=df, height=5, aspect=7/4)
g.ax.set_xlabel("",fontsize=30)
g.ax.set_ylabel("Count",fontsize=20)
g.ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
```

What did **not** work was to call set_xlabel directly on g like `g.set_xlabel()` (then I got a "Facetgrid has no set_xlabel" method error)