# Increase tick label font size in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a huge problem with my seaborn plots. For some reason, the numbers along the axis are printed with a really small font, which makes them unreadable. I've tried to scale them with

```
with plt.rc_context(dict(sns.axes_style("whitegrid"),
                     **sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5))):
    b = sns.violinplot(y="Draughts", data=dr)
```

To no help, this only makes the axis text larger, but not the number along the axis. [image: See image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328003/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-using-seaborn-facetgrid) makes fonts larger in `seaborn` ...

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Draughts": np.random.randn(100)})

# Plot using seaborn
sns.set(font_scale = 2)
b = sns.violinplot(y = "Draughts", data = df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is right: the `font_scale` changes **all** of the fonts, AFAIU. Also the titel size. Is there a way to _only_ change the tick labels?

Comment: `sns.set(); fig, ax = plt.subplots(); sns.violinplot(data = df, ax = ax); ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 30); plt.show()`

Comment: this method changes all of the fonts.

Comment: Also works `this_axis.tick_params(labelsize=14)` works, especially if you need to adjust the tick label size of several subplots

Answer (score 35):

Expanding on the accepted answer, if you want to just rescale the font size of the tick labels without scaling other labels by the same amount, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Draughts": np.random.randn(100)})

# Plot using seaborn
b = sns.violinplot(y = "Draughts", data = df)
b.set_yticklabels(b.get_yticks(), size = 15)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot link]

Comment: If your plot is a `FacetGrid` you can just do `g.set_yticklabels(size = 15)`

Comment: Yes, thank you for this answer! There are so many wrong answers suggesting to scale **all** the fonts. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 13):

- This answer will address setting x or y ticklabel size independently.
- `sns.set(font_scale=2)` from [p-robot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1764129/p-robot) will set **all the figure fonts**.
- The answer from [Kabir Ahuja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8491889/kabir-ahuja) works because y-labels position is being used as the text.

  - If there are y-labels text, that solution will not work.
- There are a number of ways to get ticks and labels:

  - `plt.xticks()`
  - `ax.get_xticklabels()`
  - `ax.get_xticks()`
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.2`, `seaborn 0.12.0`**

### Given the following plot

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# plot figure
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
p = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)

# get label text
_, ylabels = plt.yticks()
_, xlabels = plt.xticks()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Setting the y-axis doesn't work

```py
# plot figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)

print(ax.get_xticks())
print(ax.get_yticks())
print('\n')
print(ax.get_xticklabels())
print(ax.get_yticklabels())
print('\n')
print(plt.xticks())
print(plt.yticks())
print('\n')

# get label text
yticks, ylabels = plt.yticks()
xticks, xlabels = plt.xticks()

print(ylabels)

print(yticks)

# there is no text label
print(ylabels[0].get_text())

# there are text labels on the x-axis
print(xlabels)

# the answer from Kabir Ahuja works because of this
print(ax.get_yticks())

# set the x-axis ticklabel size
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, size=5)

# in this case, the following won't work because the text is ''
# this is what to do if the there are text labels
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, size=15)

plt.show()
```

#### `print` output

```
[0 1 2 3]
[-10.   0.  10.  20.  30.  40.  50.  60.  70.]

[Text(0, 0, 'Thur'), Text(1, 0, 'Fri'), Text(2, 0, 'Sat'), Text(3, 0, 'Sun')]
[Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')]

(array([0, 1, 2, 3]), [Text(0, 0, 'Thur'), Text(1, 0, 'Fri'), Text(2, 0, 'Sat'), Text(3, 0, 'Sun')])
(array([-10.,   0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.]), [Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')])

[Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')]
[-10.   0.  10.  20.  30.  40.  50.  60.  70.]
← empty string from ylabels[0].get_text()
[Text(0, 0, 'Thur'), Text(1, 0, 'Fri'), Text(2, 0, 'Sat'), Text(3, 0, 'Sun')]
[-10.   0.  10.  20.  30.  40.  50.  60.  70.]
```

#### plot

- There are no ytick labels because

  - `y_text = [y.get_text() for y in ylabels] = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`

[image]

### To set yticklabel size

```py
# use
p.set_yticklabels(p.get_yticks(), size=15)

# or
_, ylabels = plt.yticks()
p.set_yticklabels(ylabels, size=15)
```

### To set xticklabel size

```py
# use
p.set_xticklabels(p.get_xticks(), size=15)

# or
_, xlabels = plt.xticks()
p.set_xticklabels(xlabels, size=15)
```

### This works

```py
# plot figure
fig , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)

# get label text
_, xlabels = plt.xticks()

# set the x-labels with
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, size=5)

# prevents: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[1:])
# set the y-labels with
_ = ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), size=5)
```

[image]