# Font size of axis labels in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In seaborn, how can you change just the x and y axis label font size? Instead of using the "set context" method, is there a way to specifically change just the axis labels? Here is my code:

```
def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):

    r = stats.pearsonr(x, y)[0] ** 2
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r$^2$ = {:.2f}".format(r),
                xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes, fontsize=16)
    if r > 0.6:
        col = 'g'
    elif r < 0.6:
        col = 'r'
    sns.regplot(x, y, color=col)
    return r

IC_Plot = sns.PairGrid(df_IC, palette=["red"])
IC_Plot.map_offdiag(corrfunc)

IC_Plot.savefig("Save_Pair.png")
```

Comment: Use either `plt.xlabel('text', fontsize=size)` or `ax.set_xlabel('text', fontdict={'fontsize' : size})`.

Comment: Thanks, this works but for some reason it does not change the font on the last pair plot in both the x and y direction.

Comment: There are multiple subplots? You'll need to call the above method for every axis you want it to apply to, and remember that Matplotlib subplot numbering counts from 1 (unlike everything else in Python...).

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27714134/4115369

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The easiest way to change the fontsize of all x- and y- labels in a plot is to use the [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) property `"axes.labelsize"` at the beginning of the script, e.g.

```
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 15
```

You may also set the font size of each individual label

```
for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
    l = ax.get_xlabel()
    ax.set_xlabel(l, fontsize=15)
```