# how to change Label font size in Seaborn Bar plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to change the font size of the label of my Bars. The below snippet isn't working...it's almost overlapping each other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sns.set_context('paper')
report_id = ['Report_1', 'Report_2', 'Report_3', 'Report_4', 'Report_5', 'Report_6', 'Report_7', 'Report_8', 'Report_9',
             'Report_10', 'Report_11', 'Report_12', 'Report_13', 'Report_14', 'Report_15', 'Report_16', 'Report_17',
             'Report_18', 'Report_19', 'Report_20', 'Report_21', 'Report_22', 'Report_23', 'Report_24', 'Report_25',
             'Report_26', 'Report_27', 'Report_28', 'Report_29', 'Report_30', 'Report_31', 'Report_32', 'Report_33',
             'Report_34', 'Report_35', 'Report_36', 'Report_37', 'Report_38', 'Report_39', 'Report_40', 'Report_41',
             'Report_42', 'Report_43', 'Report_44', 'Report_45', 'Report_46', 'Report_47', 'Report_48', 'Report_49',
             'Report_50', 'Report_51', 'Report_52', 'Report_53', 'Report_54', 'Report_55', 'Report_56', 'Report_57',
             'Report_58', 'Report_59', 'Report_60']
report_value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
                29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,
                55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]

df = pd.DataFrame({'report_id': report_id, 'report_value': report_value})

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (12, 60)})
ax = sns.barplot(y="report_id", x="report_value", data=df, palette="GnBu_d")
ax.tick_params(labelsize=3)
initialx = 0
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.text(p.get_width(), initialx + p.get_height() / 10, "{:1.0f}".format(p.get_width()))

    initialx += 1

plt.show()
```

Output Image is: [image: IMAGE_OUTPUT]

Comment: Use the `fontsize` parameter of [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html).

Comment: Please check this to see if it works for you ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328003/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-using-seaborn-facetgrid