# editing plot - python

Tags: python, plot

Hi I have a code that plots 2D data from a .dat file (I'll call it filename.dat which is just a .dat file with 2 columns of numbers).  It works fine, I just have some questions as to how to improve it.

How can I edit my code to make the axes label larger and add a  title?  This code is not so easy to edit the way I have it written now.   I have tried adding the fontsize,title  into the plotfile(...) command, but this did not work.  Thanks for the help!  My code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#unpack file data

dat_file = np.loadtxt("filename.dat",unpack=True)
plt.plotfile('filename.dat', delimiter=' ',cols=(0,1), names=('x','y'),marker='0')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is just an opinion, but I prefer to create a figure first: `fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()`, then get the axes with `ax=fig.gca()`, and then set different properties of both. Matplotlib has got a great on-line help for everything and loads of examples: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Thanks a lot, that is what I want to do; set different properties for all of the axes. I will try to figure out how to implement that. I was looking for opinions as to how others would go about doing this, so thank you.  I am very new to python and assumed my way was not the quickest/best way to do things.

Comment: No problem. If you search for your problem I'm sure you'll find examples that'll show you how to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve. I make a plot here, set fontsizes of some things etc., could be a starting point (line 80): https://github.com/AleksanderLidtke/Hawkes-Process/blob/master/hawkes.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to add them to the plot.

You can add a title with:

```
plt.title("MyTitle")
```

and you add text to the graph with

```
# the following coordinates need to be determined with experimentation
# put them at a location and move them around if they are in
# the way of the graph
x = 5 
y = 10
plt.text(x,y, "Your comment")
```

This can help you with the font sizes:

[How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: That is very helpful, just one question for you.  How can I change the fontsize of the axes?  I tried adding fontsize = ... but this gave me an error message.  Thanks for your help!  Adding the title works excellent!

Comment: I expanded the answer to better answer your question.

Comment: The command you provided to add text to the graph: plt.text(x,y "your comment") gives me an error message since x is not defined.  By the way, I figured out all of the font sizes based on what you provided.  Thanks

Comment: you have to define what x and y are, say

    x = 5
    y = 10

Comment: Oh, I see, that is very helpful.  Thanks.