# Customizing plots in python (countplot and boxplot)

Tags: python, graph, count, boxplot, customizing

I am working on a data science project, and as I am fairly new I need some help when it comes to customzing my plots. Just a quick intro, I am working on a analysis of a dataset from Las Vegas car crashes. Here are the problems I am facing.

[Countplot for crash severity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwk6N.png) 
In the first image I would need to increase the size of the graph so the text on the x variable is visible.
The code for the plot:

```
sns.catplot(x="Crash_Seve", kind="count", data=df);
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
plt.title("Types of Crash Severity in Las Vegas car crashes")
plt.show()
```

[Boxplots comparing speed of two drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLzf6.png)
Here I would also need to increase the size so the graphs are more visible, I tried something which you can see but whatever I type in the size the graph does not increase. I would also like to plot these box plots through seaborn or matplotlib so they are a bit prettier. They both come from two different columns but have the same interpretation mph of a drive, which means both are numeric. Thank you for the input

```
boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['V1_Driver_', 'V2_Driver_'])
plt.title("Speed of both drivers")
figure(num=None, figsize=(40, 20), dpi=160, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In both examples, you can use the `figsize` option in the `figure` command (as you have tried) but you have to call `figure` **before** you plot something. I would also recommend to rotate the labels a bit [how-to-rotate-axis-labels-in-seaborn-and-matplotlib](https://www.drawingfromdata.com/how-to-rotate-axis-labels-in-seaborn-and-matplotlib) and to change the fontsize [how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot).