# How to increase Text size in ConfusionMatrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I Have a CM and want the text to be bold. So all the numbers and the labels as well.
Heres the code:

```
array = np.array([[1003, 32], [30, 51]])
labels = np.array(["Label 1", "Label 2"])
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=array, display_labels=labels)

disp = disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap="Reds", ax=None, xticks_rotation="horizontal")
plt.show()
```

Is there any easy way to change it to a bold style?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot)

Answer (score 6):

This kind of plot relies on the library matplotlib that I guess you imported as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I would suggest you to set the params for the font before your plot.

```
font = {'family' : 'normal',
    'weight' : 'bold',
    'size'   : 22}
plt.rc('font', **font)
```

If interested in more detail take a look at that question [How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot)